# Adding solvers to PuLP in Python

Tags: python-3.x, solver, pulp

I just started working with Pulp in Python 3.5 (Spyder) on OSx.

However, after running the pip install I ran the tests and some solvers are not available (e.g. CPLEX, COIN and XPRESS).

I'm trying to solve a quadratic programming problem and I'd like to use the XPRESS solver, but I cannot find how to install extra solvers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean FICO XPRESS: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FICO_Xpress.
 It is not free though. You will need to pay and download.

I have tried Coin, it is free and fast. To download, go to https://projects.coin-or.org/CoinBinary.

Pulp is an interface for the solvers, not the solvers themselves. So when you download pulp, solvers are not installed automatically. You need to download Coin, Glpk, etc. in addition to the installation of Pulp.

Comment: do you know how to add the path from the new solver to pulp?, i have a CPLEX installation in my computer, but i dont know how to set that interface with pulp.

Comment: I did not add path, after I download CPLEX, pulp automatically detected it. You can use import pulp; pulp.pulpTestAll() to see what solvers have been installed. @PabloA